# Running casper tests in android webview

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-webview, casperjs

I have tests written using casperjs for a web application.  I also have an android app that encases the application in a webview.  I want to be able to run casper tests in the android native environment.  Is there a way I can achieve it?